# this->... required in template wrapper classes

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Please help me to explain why I can not call func1() directly in this case:

```
class A {
public:
    void func1() {}
};

template <typename wrapped_type>
class B : public wrapped_type {
public:
    void func2() {
        func1();
    }
};

B<A> b;
```

The above code results in "error C3861: 'func1': identifier not found" at the func1() call. But if I replace this call by one of the following two options, then it can compile successfully:

```
this->func1();
```

or

```
wrapped_type::func1();
```

For what I learned, the template class is only truely compiled when all the type parameters are determined.

Comment: It's one of those funny things. There's probably a duplicate for this somewhere. Btw, I think `this->func1();` is preferred.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

`func1()` isn't dependent on anything that the compiler doesn't know on its first pass when it is looking at the template code without any specific template parameters provided, so it tries to look up what it can -- a global function called `func1`.

By stating `this->func1()`, it tells the compiler that it must look within the class for `func1` and the compiler knows that it cannot do that until it has a fully defined class, including the templated inheritance, so the compilation of `this->func1()` is deferred until the second pass, when the type is fully instantiated.

You could pass a `wrapped_type` where there is a func1 in which case the code must compile, or you could pass a `wrapped_typ` where there is not a func1, in which case the code must not compile, so it has to wait.